# How to Mock Spring4D Events with DUnit

Tags: unit-testing, delphi, dunit, spring4d

I am struggling to successfully mock a Spring4d Event with DUnit.

In fact I am more mocking a mock returning a mock of an event...

This is the basic structure.

```
TMyObject --EventContainer--> TMock<IEventContainer> --Event--> TMock<IEvent>
```

TMyObject has a property EventContainer : IEventContainer

IEventContainer has a property Event : IMyEvent

I want to mock

```
MyObject.EventContainer.Event.Add
```

I tested each possibility I could think of. I either get AVs or Invalid Casts. I've put the source code below. If anyone could help me to get this working that would be really nifty!

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
    System.SysUtils,
    DUnitTestRunner,
    Spring.Events,
    Spring,
    Classes,
    TestFramework,
    Delphi.Mocks;
    //Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas';

type

{$M+}
    IMyEvent = interface(IEvent<TNotifyEvent>)
        procedure Add(const handler: TMethod);
    end;
{$M-}
{$M+}

    IMyEventMock = interface(IMyEvent)
        procedure Add(const handler: TMethod);
    end;
{$M-}
{$M+}

    IEventContainer = interface(IInterface)
        function GetEvent: IMyEvent;
        procedure SetEvent(const Value: IMyEvent);
        property Event: IMyEvent
            read GetEvent
            write SetEvent;
    end;
{$M-}
{$M+}

    ITestEventContainer = interface(IEventContainer)
        function GetEvent: TMock<IMyEvent>;
        procedure SetEvent(const Value: TMock<IMyEvent>);
        property Event: TMock<IMyEvent>
            read GetEvent
            write SetEvent;
    end;
{$M-}
{$REGION 'TEventContainer'}

    TEventContainer = class(TInterfacedObject, IEventContainer)

    private
        FAEvent: IMyEvent;
        function GetEvent: IMyEvent;
        procedure SetEvent(const Value: IMyEvent);

    public
        property Event: IMyEvent
            read GetEvent
            write SetEvent;
    end;

{$ENDREGION}
{$REGION 'TMyObject'}

    TMyObject = class(TObject)
    private
        FEventContainer: IEventContainer;
        function GetEventContainer: IEventContainer;
        procedure SetEventContainer(const Value: IEventContainer);

    public
        property EventContainer: IEventContainer
            read GetEventContainer
            write SetEventContainer;
    end;

{$ENDREGION}
{$REGION 'TMyObjectTest'}

    TMyObjectTest = class(TTestCase)
    strict private
        FMyObject: TMyObject;
        FMyEventContainerMock: TMock<IEventContainer>;
        FMyTestEventContainerMock: TMock<ITestEventContainer>;
        FEventMock: TMock<IMyEventMock>;

    public
        procedure SetUp; override;
        procedure TearDown; override;

    published
        procedure Test_InstanceAsValue;
        procedure Test_Value_Make;
        procedure Test_Value_From;
        procedure Test_Value_From_Instance;
        procedure Test_Value_From_Variant;
        procedure Test_Value_From_Variant_Instance;
        procedure Test_Mocked_Container_Value_Make;
        procedure Test_Mocked_Container_Value_From;
        procedure Test_Mocked_Container_Value_From_Instance;
        procedure Test_Mocked_Container_Value_From_Variant;
        procedure Test_Mocked_Container_Value_From_Variant_Instance;
    end;
{$ENDREGION}


{$REGION 'TEventContainer'}

function TEventContainer.GetEvent: IMyEvent;
begin
    Result := FAEvent;
end;

procedure TEventContainer.SetEvent(const Value: IMyEvent);
begin
    FAEvent := Value;
end;
{$ENDREGION}

{$REGION 'TMyObject'}

function TMyObject.GetEventContainer: IEventContainer;
begin
    Result := FEventContainer;
end;

procedure TMyObject.SetEventContainer(const Value: IEventContainer);
begin
    FEventContainer := Value;
end;
{$ENDREGION}

{$REGION 'TMyObjectTest'}

procedure TMyObjectTest.SetUp;
begin
    inherited;

    FMyObject := TMyObject.Create;

    FMyEventContainerMock := TMock<IEventContainer>.Create;

    FMyObject.EventContainer := FMyEventContainerMock;

end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.TearDown;
begin
    inherited;

    FMyObject.Free;

    FMyObject := nil;
end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.Test_Value_Make;
var aValue : TValue;
begin
    FEventMock := TMock<IMyEventMock>.Create;

    TValue.Make(@FEventMock, TypeInfo(IMyEventMock), aValue);

    FMyEventContainerMock.SetUp.WillReturnDefault('GetEvent', aValue);

    FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.Test_InstanceAsValue;
begin
    FEventMock := TMock<IMyEventMock>.Create;

    FMyEventContainerMock.SetUp.WillReturnDefault('GetEvent', FEventMock.InstanceAsValue);

    FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.Test_Mocked_Container_Value_From;
begin

    FMyTestEventContainerMock := TMock<ITestEventContainer>.Create;

    FMyObject.EventContainer := FMyTestEventContainerMock;

    FEventMock := TMock<IMyEventMock>.Create;

    FMyTestEventContainerMock.SetUp.WillReturnDefault('GetEvent', FEventMock.InstanceAsValue);

    FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;

end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.Test_Mocked_Container_Value_From_Instance;
begin
FMyTestEventContainerMock := TMock<ITestEventContainer>.Create;

    FMyObject.EventContainer := FMyTestEventContainerMock;

    FEventMock := TMock<IMyEventMock>.Create;

    FMyTestEventContainerMock.SetUp.WillReturnDefault('GetEvent', TValue.From(FEventMock));

    FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.Test_Mocked_Container_Value_From_Variant;
begin
    FMyTestEventContainerMock := TMock<ITestEventContainer>.Create;

    FMyObject.EventContainer := FMyTestEventContainerMock;

    FEventMock := TMock<IMyEventMock>.Create;

    FMyTestEventContainerMock.SetUp.WillReturnDefault('GetEvent', TValue.FromVariant(FEventMock));

    FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.Test_Mocked_Container_Value_From_Variant_Instance;
begin
    FMyTestEventContainerMock := TMock<ITestEventContainer>.Create;

    FMyObject.EventContainer := FMyTestEventContainerMock;

    FEventMock := TMock<IMyEventMock>.Create;

    FMyTestEventContainerMock.SetUp.WillReturnDefault('GetEvent', TValue.FromVariant(FEventMock.Instance));

    FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.Test_Mocked_Container_Value_Make;
var aValue : TValue;
begin
    FMyTestEventContainerMock := TMock<ITestEventContainer>.Create;

    FMyObject.EventContainer := FMyTestEventContainerMock;

    FEventMock := TMock<IMyEventMock>.Create;

    TValue.Make(@aValue, TypeInfo(TMock<IMyEventMock>), aValue);

    FMyTestEventContainerMock.SetUp.WillReturnDefault('GetEvent', aValue);

    FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.Test_Value_From;
begin
    FEventMock := TMock<IMyEventMock>.Create;

    FMyEventContainerMock.SetUp.WillReturnDefault('GetEvent', TValue.From(FEventMock));

    FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.Test_Value_From_Instance;
begin
    FEventMock := TMock<IMyEventMock>.Create;

    FMyEventContainerMock.SetUp.WillReturnDefault('GetEvent', TValue.From(FEventMock.Instance));

    FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.Test_Value_From_Variant;
begin
    FEventMock := TMock<IMyEventMock>.Create;

    FMyEventContainerMock.SetUp.WillReturnDefault('GetEvent', TValue.FromVariant(FEventMock));

    FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
end;

procedure TMyObjectTest.Test_Value_From_Variant_Instance;
begin
    FEventMock := TMock<IMyEventMock>.Create;

    FMyEventContainerMock.SetUp.WillReturnDefault('GetEvent', TValue.FromVariant(FEventMock.Instance));

    FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
end;

begin
    RegisterTest(TMyObjectTest.Suite);
    try
        DUnitTestRunner.RunRegisteredTests;
        ReadLn;
    except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
            Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
            ReadLn;
        end;
    end;

end.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First your approach is wrong. Inheriting an interface and then adding `{$M+}` will only include method info for the methods added from there on. That means even if you add a method with the same signature as a parent interface has will not make the mock work because the code will still call the parent interfaces method and not the one you added.

Furthermore DelphiMocks in this case is the victim of a bug in TValue conversion of an interface to its parent type. This is just not supported - see `Rtti.ConvIntf2Intf`.

I would suggest compiling Spring4D with IEvent inheriting from IInvokable to get method info in there and avoid inheriting from it.

If you do that the following tests will pass - all others are just passing the mock wrong:

```
Test_InstanceAsValue;
Test_Value_From_Instance;
Test_Mocked_Container_Value_From;
```

In Spring4D 1.2 we are introducing a new interception library that is also used for our mocking solution. Also the container will be able to provide automocking. So you can write your test like this:

```
var
  container: TContainer;
  event: IMyEvent;
begin
  container := TContainer.Create;
  container.AddExtension<TAutoMockExtension>;
  try
    FMyObject.EventContainer := container.Resolve<ITestEventContainer>;

    event := FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
    event.Add(nil);
  finally
    container.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The container will create mocks for any type it needs to resolve that it does not know. In this test you could register the class you want to test and the container automatically injects any dependency as mock.

```
var
  container: TContainer;
  event: IMyEvent;
begin
  container := TContainer.Create;
  container.AddExtension<TAutoMockExtension>;
  container.RegisterType<TMyObject>.InjectProperty('EventContainer');
  container.Build;
  try
    FMyObject := container.Resolve<TMyObject>;

    event := FMyObject.EventContainer.Event;
    event.Add(nil);
  finally
    container.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You can go even further and integrate the auto mocking container into a base testcase class:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils,
  DUnitTestRunner,
  TestFramework,
  Spring.Events,
  Spring,
  Spring.Container,
  Spring.Container.Registration,
  Spring.Container.AutoMockExtension,
  Spring.Mocking;

type
  IMyEvent = IEvent<TNotifyEvent>;

  IEventContainer = interface(IInvokable)
    function GetEvent: IMyEvent;
    procedure SetEvent(const Value: IMyEvent);
    property Event: IMyEvent read GetEvent write SetEvent;
  end;

  TMyObject = class(TObject)
  private
    FEventContainer: IEventContainer;
  public
    property EventContainer: IEventContainer read FEventContainer write FEventContainer;
  end;

  TAutoMockingTestCase<T: class> = class(TTestCase)
  protected
    fContainer: TContainer;
    fSUT: T;
    procedure SetUp; overload; override;
    procedure TearDown; override;
    procedure SetUp(const registration: TRegistration<T>); reintroduce; overload; virtual;
  end;

  TMyTest = class(TAutoMockingTestCase<TMyObject>)
  protected
    procedure SetUp(const registration: TRegistration<TMyObject>); override;
  published
    procedure Test_EventAdd;
  end;

procedure TAutoMockingTestCase<T>.SetUp(const registration: TRegistration<T>);
begin
end;

procedure TAutoMockingTestCase<T>.SetUp;
begin
  inherited;
  fContainer := TContainer.Create;
  fContainer.AddExtension<TAutoMockExtension>;
  SetUp(fContainer.RegisterType<T>);
  fContainer.Build;
  fSUT := fContainer.Resolve<T>;
end;

procedure TAutoMockingTestCase<T>.TearDown;
begin
  fSUT.Free;
  fContainer.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyTest.SetUp(const registration: TRegistration<TMyObject>);
begin
  registration.InjectProperty('EventContainer');
end;

procedure TMyTest.Test_EventAdd;
begin
  fSUT.EventContainer.Event.Add(nil);
end;

begin
  RegisterTest(TMyTest.Suite);
  try
    DUnitTestRunner.RunRegisteredTests;
    ReadLn;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      ReadLn;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I will try this out. Can I try out the interception library in the latest master commit of spring4d?

Comment: No, in develop, master will always only contain released versions.